# Separate a java application or modifying it while running?

Tags: java, auto-update

I'm making a launcher for a java app (which updates the app, if there is a new version). The main class has a public static variable, whick holds the version number, the user has (locally). On a web server I store the newest version number, so if the two doesn't equal, the launcher updates the app. How should I access the local version number? I don't want to make just a text file, and store it there, it would be way too easy to modify. As I saied, I have a version number in my main class. But the launcher and the application are separated. Should I merge them? I think it is dangerous to modify the program while running (overwrite the whole jar file or classes). Or not even possible (?).

Comment: have a **signed** text file

Answer (score 0):

Write a Class that is responsible for your version number and serialize it to file. Serialized  value can be somehow deciphered in order to make it harder to read.

But since you are not obfuscating your code, any "I don't want to keep it in text file" are pointless.